# Python crontab - How to check if cron is running?

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I currently have a python script at

```
/home/ubuntu/test/test.py
```

When this script runs, it writes to a file

```
/home/ubuntu/test/test.txt
```

I am completely new to cron, and not very familiar with linux in general. I am trying to set up a cronjob that basically runs this script every minute.

I saw some people suggest `#!/usr/bin/env python` so I added it, but I noticed I don't even have a env folder in /usr/bin

I then ran `chmod -x test.py`. Then added an entry to cron `* * * * * /home/ubuntu/test/test.py`. Noted this wasn't working and saw someone suggest trying `* * * * * /home/ubuntu/test/test.py 2>&1 /tmp/testlog.log`. But when I check `/tmp` i only see a folder `crontab.8Rxowt/crontab/cron` and i don't see any log file created.

I am kind of confused now, I can't figure out why nothing is being updated at all. I'm not sure if the script being run needs to be placed somewhere specific, or if I screwed something up with my cron installation, or something else altogether.

**I noticed trying to run ./test.py gives permission denied, and sudo ./test.py gives command not found. Is my shebang not working? I verified im using unix line endings.**

Answer (score 1):

To make it run every minute you have to add the path to python from your system:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python cd /path_to/test.py
```

I suggest you to test it with a simple command such as "touch"

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch cd /path_to/test.txt
```

https://crontab.guru/every-1-minute